# RestHeart passing multiple parametrs in aggregation

Tags: spring, mongodb, restheart

Basically I am trying to use REST hreat to create two variables issuerId and sectionName. I am trying to get data from the URI mentioned below

```
http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getDataByIssuerAndSectionName?avars={"issuerId":19038},{"sectionName":"ASSETS"}
```

My aggregation definition is a below

```
{"$push" : {
"aggrs": 
{
  "type": "pipeline",
  "uri": "getDataByIssuerAndSectionName",
  "stages": [
    {
      "_$match": {
        "_$and": [
          {"issuerId": {"_$var": "issuerId" }},
          {
            "sectionName": {"_$var": "sectionName"}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_$unwind": "$sections"
    },
    {
      "_$unwind": "$sections.data"
    },
    {
      "_$unwind": "$sections.data.values"
    },
    {
      "_$match": {
        "_$and": [
          {"issuerId": {"_$var": "issuerId" }},
          {
            "sectionName": {"_$var": "sectionName"}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

I am sure I am doing something wring in either defining the aggregation or while requesting the URI. There is not enough in the documentation. Please help me with this request.

Comment: Never mind I go the answer

Comment: http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getDataByIssuerAndSectionName?avars={%22issuerId%22:19038,%22sectionName%22:%22ASSETS%22}